# How can you write a citation for a screenshot from a YouTube video in APA style?

Tags: citation-style

I need to use a still from a YouTube video in my presentation and I'll have to cite it in APA style. How can this be done? I've done something like:

Channel Name. (Year). Title of video [Video]. YouTube. URL to video

Would this be enough or do I need to add something to make it apparent that I used a screenshot from this video?

Comment: There are examples of APA video citations [here](https://libguides.umgc.edu/c.php?g=1003870&p=7270674#:~:text=Date%3A%20List%20the%20date%20between,video%2C%20followed%20by%20a%20period.). If it's just a screenshow, I would add the time.

Comment: Using the [format description](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/32797/17254) to state it's a screenshot might make sense, assuming on exists for video citations.